# How to assign value to function parameter in python

Tags: python

I'd like to initialise a variable inside a function (so that the final print statement in my example outputs 10):

```
def init_param(param):
    param = 10

n = 1
init_param(n)
print n                   # prints 1
```

Is this doable in python?

Comment: You can't do it. Parameters are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: You need to return `param` and assign the value to `n`

Comment: wrap it with a mutable data type. e.g. list

Comment: @Barmar there's nothing like "pass by value" or "pass by reference" in Python.

Comment: @Barmar [Is Python call-by-value or call-by-reference? Neither.](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/11/13/is-python-callbyvalue-or-callbyreference-neither/)

Comment: It's call-by-value, but the value can be a mutable object, which is not copied.

Comment: @Barmar this dead horse has already be beaten to hell and back and that was yyyeeeeaaarrrsss ago, so have mercy and let the poor animal rest in peace. The "by value" / "by reference" concepts have a well understood meaning that just do __not__ apply to what Python variables really are, so using those concepts is misleading at best.

Comment: See also [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) by @NedBatchelder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are assigned inside the function as it's local variables. So all principles apply here.

- Immutable objects cannot be changed.
- Mutable objects can be modified in place.

you're indenting to modify an immutable object, which is not possible. So your only options are :-

```
def init_param(param):
    param = 10
    return param

n = 1
n = init_param(n)
print n
```

which is pretty much useless OR

```
def init_param(param):
    param[0] = 10

n = [1]
init_param(n)
print n
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all python function passes the value by object and the reference name here `param` is just a reference to a value hold by `n`.

Now coming to the solution, yes it could be possible provided you pass the variable name

```
def init_param(var_name):
    globals()[var_name] = 10

n = 1
init_param('n')
print n
```

Hope it will answer!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Longer answer: in

```
def init_param(param):
    param = 10
```

the name `param` is local to the `init_param` function. Rebinding this name will change the value bound to the name `param` in the function's local scope, but will have absolutely no effect on the name `n` in the caller's scope - those names live in totally distinct namespaces. You can [read Ned Batcheler's reference article on Python's names and binding](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for more in-depth explanations.

What would work would be to use a mutable container - a `dict` for example - and mutate this container, ie:

```
def init_param(params, name, value):
    params[name] = value

params = {
   "n": 1,
   "answer": 42,
   "parrot": "dead"
   }

init_params(params, "n", 10)
print(params)
```

(if you don't understand why this one works, re-read Ned Batcheler's article linked above)

Answer (score 0):

```
def init_param(param):
    param = 10

n = 1
init_param(n)
print n
```

here `n` is a integer (`immutable data type`) so it will be passed by value and so value of n will be unchanged.

lets take a `mutable data type` (ex. list) then it will be passed by referenced and so values in list will be changed.

```
def init_param(a):
    a[0] = 10

arr = [1] 
init_param(arr)
print(arr[0]) # print 10
```

so you have to check first whether the data is mutable or immutable.

otherwise you can use `global keyword` to access `global variables`.

```
def f():
    global n
    n = 10
n = 1
f()
print(n) # print 10
```